# Gnome session uses KDE default cursor

Tags: 10.04, gnome, kde

I installed KDE over my Ubuntu 10.04 installation. Now when I log into gnome I get the KDE default cursor instead of the usual one. It's a minor issue but one I'd like to deal with especially since I'll probably learn something in the process. :)

KDE works fine though I've decided I prefer gnome aesthetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE probably created an `~/.icons/default/index.theme` file. If you delete that, your GNOME cursor will show up again after you log out and in again.

Comment: ~/.icons is empty. Is there anything else I should look for?
If it helps, when shutting down I get a Kubuntu screen.

Comment: @Yitzchak that isn't affecting your cursor - I'm not sure what else could be causing your cursor to show something else. Are you using compiz?

Comment: I am using compiz.

Comment: @Yitzchak in such a case I would suggest checking to see if you are hit by the compiz bug that prevents compiz from reading the gconf value of your cursor correctly. There are numerous questions on here regarding it.

Comment: Yup, that's the bug. I'll mark your answer as the solution.